# Inserting dynamically generated form data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple HTML form with three fields name,school and city. Also within the form, I have a button which I am using to insert a sub form with values neighbourhood and population. The crud mechanism is using jquery append.

In my database, I am saving the main form data in one table and the sub form data in another table.

My question is, during the creation of data in the main form,  if I insert the data of the main form into one table and get the last inserted Id and use  the id as a reference when inserting data into the second table, will this approach always work in both mysql and ms SQL?

If not is there a better approach I can adopt?

Comment: It will surely work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, as long as your dynamically created input has the proper name attribute..

For example: `name="txt_neighbourhood"`